# How to camelcase only a specific part of a string?

Tags: regex, vim

I have a CSV file like that:

```
"","LESCHELLES","","LESCHELLES"
"","SAINTE CROIX DE VERDON","","SAINTE CROIX DE VERDON"
"","SERRE CHEVALIER","","SERRE CHEVALIER"
"","SAINT JUST D'ARDECHE","","SAINT JUST D'ARDECHE"
"","NEUVILLE SUR VANNES","","NEUVILLE SUR VANNES"
"","ESCUEILLENS ET SAINT JUST","","ESCUEILLENS ET SAINT JUST"
"","PAS DES LANCIERS","","PAS DES LANCIERS"
"","PLAN DE CAMPAGNE","","PLAN DE CAMPAGNE"
```

And I'd like to convert it this way:

```
"","Leschelles","","LESCHELLES"
"","Sainte Croix De Verdon","","SAINTE CROIX DE VERDON","STE CROIX DE VERDON","93"
"","Serre Chevalier","","SERRE CHEVALIER","SERRE CHEVALIER","93"
"","Saint Just D'Ardeche","","SAINT JUST D'ARDECHE"
"","Neuville Sur Vannes","","NEUVILLE SUR VANNES"
"","Escueillens Et Saint Just","","ESCUEILLENS ET SAINT JUST","ESCUEILLENS ET ST JUST","91"
"","Luc","","LUC"
"","Pas Des Lanciers","","PAS DES LANCIERS","PAS DES LANCIERS","93"
"","Plan De Campagne","","PLAN DE CAMPAGNE","PLAN DE CAMPAGNE","93"
```

This would be nice. And better: lowercase all "whole" words like `de`, `d'`, `et`, `sur` and `des`. This would give:

```
"","Leschelles","","LESCHELLES"
"","Sainte Croix de Verdon","","SAINTE CROIX DE VERDON","STE CROIX DE VERDON","93"
"","Serre Chevalier","","SERRE CHEVALIER","SERRE CHEVALIER","93"
"","Saint Just d'Ardeche","","SAINT JUST D'ARDECHE"
"","Neuville sur Vannes","","NEUVILLE SUR VANNES"
"","Escueillens et Saint Just","","ESCUEILLENS ET SAINT JUST","ESCUEILLENS ET ST JUST","91"
"","Luc","","LUC"
"","Pas des Lanciers","","PAS DES LANCIERS","PAS DES LANCIERS","93"
"","Plan de Campagne","","PLAN DE CAMPAGNE","PLAN DE CAMPAGNE","93"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has [`title()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.title):

> Return a titlecased version of the string where words start with an
>   uppercase character and the remaining characters are lowercase.
>
> The algorithm uses a simple language-independent definition of a word
>   as groups of consecutive letters. The definition works in many
>   contexts but it means that apostrophes in contractions and possessives
>   form word boundaries, which may not be the desired result:

```
"they're bill's friends from the UK".title() "They'Re Bill'S Friends From The Uk"
```

> A workaround for apostrophes can be constructed
>   using regular expressions:

```
 import re
 def titlecase(s):
     return re.sub(r"[A-Za-z]+('[A-Za-z]+)?",
                   lambda mo: mo.group(0)[0].upper() +
                              mo.group(0)[1:].lower(),
                   s)

 titlecase("they're bill's friends.") "They're Bill's Friends."
```

---

Update: here's the solution for French problem:

```
import re, sys 

def titlecase(s):
    return re.sub(r"[A-Za-z]+('[A-Za-z]+)?",
        lambda mo: mo.group(0)[0].upper() +
                   mo.group(0)[1:].lower(),
        s)  

def french_parse(s):
    p = re.compile(
        r"( de la | sur | sous | la | de | les | du | le | au | aux | en | des | et )|(( d'| l')([a-z]+))",
        re.IGNORECASE)
    return p.sub(
        lambda mo: mo.group().find("'")>0
                   and mo.group()[:mo.group().find("'")+1].lower() +
                       titlecase(mo.group()[mo.group().find("'")+1:])
                   or (mo.group(0)[0].upper() + mo.group(0)[1:].lower()),
        s); 

for line in sys.stdin:
    s = line[20:len(line)-1]
    p = s.find('"')
    t = s[:p]
    # Just output to show which names have been modified:
    if french_parse( titlecase(t) ) != titlecase(t):
        print '"' + french_parse( titlecase(t) ) + '"'
```

Just launch it like this:

```
python thepythonscript.py < file.csv
```

Then the output will be:

```
"Grenand les Sombernon"
"Touville sur Montfort"
"Fontenay en Vexin"
"Durfort Saint Martin de Sossenac"
"Monclar d'Armagnac"
"Ports sur Vienne"
"Saint Barthelemy de Beaurepaire"
"Saint Bernard du Touvet"
"Rosoy le Vieil"
```

Comment: I'd like to mix your answer with the answer above, do you know in python how to read `stdin` like (= the equivalent in Php of `file('php://stdin')`)?

Comment: `import fileinput; for line in fileinput.input(): print line`

Comment: Funny, in French I'd like to get the opposite: `titlecase("JUST D'ARDECHE") => Just d'Ardeche`

Comment: I've done my own function that works, and that works with your solution. I've edited your file, added my solution, and checked your answer as valid. Don't hesitate to correct my "addendum" if I've made a mistake.

Comment: Still, you can just pull it into vim using `:!`.

Comment: Even easier, you can call/run python functions inside vim.

Answer (score 1):

While you may be able to pull this off with some vim regex magic, I think it'll be easier if you solve the problem in your favorite scripting language, and pipe selected text through that from vim using the `!` command. Here's an (untested) example in PHP:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$specialWords = array('de', 'd\'', 'et', 'du', /* etc. */ );
foreach (file('php://stdin') as $ville) {
    $line = ucwords($line);
    foreach ($specialWords as $w) {
        $line = preg_replace("/\\b$w\\b/i", $w, $line);
    }
    echo $line;
}
```

Make that script executable and store it somewhere on your `PATH`; then from vim, select some text and use `:'<,'>! yourscript.php` to convert (or just `:%! yourscript.php` for the whole buffer).

Comment: This is a very useful way of parsing a file into vim. **`;)`**

Answer (score 0):

The [csv.vim ftplugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2830) helps with working in CSV files. Though it does not offer a "substitute in column N" function directly, it may get your near that. At least you can arrange the columns into neat blocks, and then apply a simple regexp or visual blockwise selection to it.

But I second that using a different toolchain that is more suited to manipulating CSV-files may be preferable over doing this completely in Vim. It also depends on whether it's a one-off task or, you do this frequently.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it looks like you thought the problem is in CSV file (or generally in separators). The problem is just about "camelcase-ing" words, so sorry if my question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Yeah, from your example I thought the challenge is in combining the matching of a CSV column with the substitution, which by itself isn't that hard (except for those French exceptions). BTW, you're asking for camelCase, but actually want Title Case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an oneliner vim command.

```
%s/"[^"]*",\zs\("[^"]*"\)/\=substitute(substitute(submatch(0), '\<\(\a\)\(\a*\)\>', '\u\1\L\2', 'g'), '\c\<\(de\|d\|l\|sur\|le\|la\|en\|et\)\>', '\L&', 'g')
```

I expect here to have no double-quotes in the first two fields.

The idea behind this solution is to rely on `:h :s\=` to execute a series of functions on the second field once found. The series of functions being: first change each word to TitleCase, then put all *liants* in lowercase.